# Insert into with Select and Sum

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

So I am trying to Insert Into one Table from a Select Query of another table.  I figured I had to do it this way because I am trying to SUM several columns within the Insert.  Ultimately I want this to be a stored procedure to move data from a Staging Table to more normalized data.  The error I am getting is a syntax error on whatever the last character in the query is.  Any help or suggestions you can supply would be most appreciated.   Here is my query:

```
    INSERT INTO ShippingCost (WebOrder, Zone, NetAmount, EnteredWeight, BilledWeight,      Carrier)
SELECT WebOrder, Zone, NetAmount, EnteredWeight, BilledWeight, Carrier
FROM

    (select  substring([Package Reference Number 5],4,9) as WebOrder
             , zone
             , sum(CAST([Net Amount] as Money)) as NetAmount
             , sum(CAST([Entered Weight] as decimal)) as EnteredWeight
             , sum(CAST([Billed Weight] as INT)) as BilledWeight
             , 'UPS' as Carrier

               from UpsStaging
               where [Package Reference Number 5] LIKE 'WEB%[^0-9]%'
               group by [Package Reference Number 5],zone
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an alias to the end of the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO ShippingCost (WebOrder, Zone, NetAmount, EnteredWeight, BilledWeight,      Carrier)
SELECT WebOrder, Zone, NetAmount, EnteredWeight, BilledWeight, Carrier
FROM
(select  substring([Package Reference Number 5],4,9) as WebOrder
 , zone
 , sum(CAST([Net Amount] as Money)) as NetAmount
 , sum(CAST([Entered Weight] as decimal)) as EnteredWeight
 , sum(CAST([Billed Weight] as INT)) as BilledWeight
 , 'UPS' as Carrier

   from UpsStaging
   where [Package Reference Number 5] LIKE 'WEB%[^0-9]%'
   group by [Package Reference Number 5],zone
) as [subq]
```

Does the subquery work?  I wouldn't expect the group by line to work properly -- instead, use this: `GROUP BY substring([Package Reference Number 5],4,9), zone`

Comment: Hey the alias worked!!  I have been staring at this for two days...yes the sub query worked, but I put your edits in anyway.  THanks a lot!!.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to alias your derived table, even if you don't refer to the alias.  Put a "x" after the closing parentheses.